# How to retrieve latitude and longitude from firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Latitude and Longitude are stored under `geopoint instance` .  When i try to fetch them getting `Instance of 'GeoPoint` . How to retrieve latitude and longitude from firestore ? .

[image]

Comment: You can use `firestoreInstance.uptade`

Comment: Could you be more specific i cannot understand ? @theiskaa

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66086230/14247462 check this answer

Comment: DocReference mydoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc("Users/uid/location").get()
mydoc.get("current_coordinates.geopoint") @Pavel

Comment: @theiskaa That's not the answer i'm looking for. My question is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fetch location data form firebase you will always receive a GeoPoint. The GeoPoint class has 2 variables: latitude, longitude. Just cast the fetched data to the GeoPoint class: (data as GeoPoint).latitude, (data as GeoPoint).longitude.